# Grouping of lines in a text file and further processing

Tags: python

I have an input file in the format below. This is just a sample file, the actual file has many entries in the same way:

```
0.0 aa:bb:cc dd:ee:ff 100  000 ---------->line1
0.2 aa:bb:cc dd:ee:ff 101  011 ---------->line2
0.5 dd:ee:ff aa:bb:cc 230  001 ---------->line3
0.9 dd:ee:ff aa:bb:cc 231  110 ---------->line4
1.2 dd:ee:ff aa:bb:cc 232  101 ---------->line5
1.4 aa:bb:cc dd:ee:ff 102  1111 ---------->line6
1.6 aa:bb:cc dd:ee:ff 103  1101 ---------->line7
1.7 aa:bb:cc dd:ee:ff 108  1001 ---------->line8
2.4 dd:ee:ff aa:bb:cc 233  1000 ---------->line9  
2.8 gg:hh:ii jj:kk:ll 450  1110 ---------->line10
3.2 jj:kk:ll gg:hh:ii 600  010 ---------->line11
```

First column represents timestamp, second source address, third destination address, fourth sequence number, fifth not needed.

For this problem, definition of a group:

```
i. The lines should be consecutive(lines 1 and 2)  
ii. Should have same second and third column, but fourth column should be differed by 1.
```

I need to calculate timestamp difference of first line in group and the first line of the next, for all groups corresponding to same (column2, column3).
For example, the groups corresponding to (aa:bb:cc dd:ee:ff) are (line1, line2) & (lin6, line7) & (line8). The final output should be like, (aa:bb:cc dd:ee:ff) = [1.4 0.3].
Because 1.4 = timestamp difference between line6, line1. 0.3 is time difference between line8, line 6 of (aa:bb:cc dd:ee:ff) entry.
These should be calculated against all (column2 column3) pairs.

I have written a program which counts the number of members in a group which is as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

with open("luawrite") as f:
#read the first line and set the number from it as the value of `prev`
    num = next(f).rsplit(None,2)[-2:]
    prev  = int(num)
    count = 1                               #initialize `count` to 1
    for lin in f:
            num = lin.rsplit(None,2)[-2:]
            num  = int(num)                    #use `str.rsplit` for minimum splits
            if num - prev == 1:               #if current `num` - `prev` == 1
                    count+=1                          # increment `count`
                    prev = num                        # set `prev` = `num`
            else:
                    print count                #else print `count` or write it to a file
                    count = 1                        #reset `count` to 1
                    prev = num                       #set `prev` = `num`
    if num - prev !=1:
            print count
```

I tried various methods by making 2nd and 3rd columns as dictionary keys, but there are multiple groups corresponding to the same key. This sounds like a tough task to me. Please help me solve this tricky problem.

Comment: Seems to me like a complete retranscription of an homework and a code sample given by the teacher, isn't it? What effort did you made to tranform the problem in pseudo-code or logical sequence to solve it?

Comment: @Le Droid...This is not an homework. I am not a student. This is just a requirement in one of my own program learning. I tried using dictionary, but the dictionary should not be keyed on (column2, column3) as i cannot divide it into groups for same key. I am out of ideas. I posted it here because stackoverflow always helped me get ideas.

Comment: @JustinCarrey, why do you have line 8 in the group? column 4 is not line7 + 1?

Comment: @perreal..Yes, i put that line purposefully. because (line6, line7) and (line8) should fall in different groups since the column4 value differ by more than 1.

Comment: I saw question about this `aa:bb:cc` `dd:ee:ff` stuff yesterday. Which book are you getting this problem from? 8)

Comment: @2rs2ts...its not from book. I generally make up these entries to explain the problem i am trying to solve

Comment: @JustinCarrey Seems a duplicate of the question you asked yesterday on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305726/challenging-way-of-counting-entries-of-a-file-dynamically. People here are really nice and work a lot for you...

Comment: @Le Droid People here help me, not work for me. And as you can see, there is a lot of difference in both the problems. The questions appear similar because i make up the entries present in the input file, and everytime they are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = list()
groups = defaultdict(list)
i = 1
with open('input') as f:
    for line in f:
        row = line.strip().split() + [ i ]
        gname = " ".join(row[1:3])
        groups[gname] += [ row ]
        i += 1

output = defaultdict(list)
for gname, group in groups.items():
    gr = []
    last_key,last_col4, last_idx='',-1,-1
    for row in group:
        key, idx = " ".join(row[1:3]), int(row[-1])
        keys_same   = last_key == key and last_col4 + 1 == int(row[3])
        consequtive = last_idx + 1 == idx
        if not (gr and keys_same and consequtive):
            if gr: output[gr[0][1]] += [ float(row[0]) - float(gr[0][0]) ]
            gr = [ row ]
        else: gr += [ row ]
        last_key, last_col4, last_idx = key, int(row[3]), idx

for k,v in output.items():
    print k, ' --> ', v
```

Comment: the values are correct, but every line is printing column2, column3 along with time difference. How can i print it like (aa:bb:cc) -> [1.0 2.0 3.0]...Now it is printing aa:bb:cc dd:ee:ff 1.0; aa:bb:cc dd:ee:ff 2.0; aa:bb:cc dd:ee:ff 3.0;........

Comment: @perreal....there seems to be some small mistake somewhere. First it is not printing (column2 column3) as keys. It is only printing either column 1 or column2. Second, each key-->value is contiguous, not each appearing in each line. Third, i can see only 1 dictionary entry. And last, the output is wrong. Thanks a lot for the great effort. Previous program(before edit) worked perfectly. I just need to group them under corresponding common key. for clarity, please run the program on the text file i have given. You will understand.

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) could be used to extract groups defined by:

> i. The lines should be consecutive(lines 1 and 2)
>
> ii. Should have
>   same second and third column, but fourth column should be differed by 1

Then [`collections.defaultdict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections#collections.defaultdict) could be used to collect timestamps to find the differences:

> I need to calculate timestamp difference of first line in group and
>   the first line of the next, for all groups corresponding to same
>   (column2, column3).

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby

import sys
file = sys.stdin # could be anything that yields lines e.g., a regular file

rows = (line.split() for line in file if line.strip())

# get timestamps map: (source, destination) -> timestamps of 1st lines
timestamps = defaultdict(list) 
for ((source, dest), _), group in groupby(enumerate(rows),
                           key=lambda (i, row): (row[1:3], i - int(row[3]))):
    ts = float(next(group)[1][0]) # a timestamp from the 1st line in a group
    timestamps[source, dest].append(ts)

# find differences
for (source, dest), t in sorted(timestamps.items(), key=lambda (x,y): x):
    diffs = [b - a for a, b in zip(t, t[1:])] # pairwise differences   
    info = ", ".join(map(str, diffs)) if diffs else t # support unique
    print("{source} {dest}: {info}".format(**vars()))
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/K74um6)

```
aa:bb:cc dd:ee:ff: 1.4, 0.3
dd:ee:ff aa:bb:cc: 1.9
gg:hh:ii jj:kk:ll: [2.8]
jj:kk:ll gg:hh:ii: [3.2]
```

`[]` means that there is a single group of the corresponding (source address, destination address) pairs in the input i.e., there is nothing to construct the difference from. You could [prepend a dummy `0.0` timestamp to the timestamps lists to handle all cases uniformly](http://ideone.com/r3w6oz).